# this query shows #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT X.workorder_id,X.order_id FROM mr_workorder_data AS X 
    LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT order_id, workorder_id, GROUP_CONCAT(trim_id SEPARATOR '|') AS trim_id_arr 
   FROM mr_workorder_data 
          WHERE order_id = X.order_id AND workorder_id = 
X.workorder_id GROUP BY order_id) 
WHERE X.data_type = 'Accessories' GROUP BY X.workorder_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a left join  (    subselect )  without an alias  add  (eg:)  T at the end of the subquery ()

```
  SELECT X.workorder_id,X.order_id 
  FROM mr_workorder_data AS X 
  LEFT JOIN (  SELECT order_id,workorder_id,
           GROUP_CONCAT(trim_id SEPARATOR '|') AS trim_id_arr 
  FROM mr_workorder_data 
  WHERE order_id = X.order_id AND workorder_id = X.workorder_id
  GROUP BY order_id   )  T 
  WHERE X.data_type = 'Accessories' 
  GROUP BY X.workorder_id
```